# Potential problems using CSVs to populate data for high traffic site?

Tags: csv, highcharts

I was told by somebody that CSVs could present problems with a fair amount of traffic accessing the CSV file or if it is written to at the same time it is accessed. But I have also been finding posts on this board recommending using CSVs to prepare Highcharts data.

Will using CSVs, that may eventually become large, present a problem in either of these two scenarios?

Comment: I guess I am unsure how a CSV would present more a problem than just any normal html file under these conditions, they are all just text files

Answer (score 0):

Both. A database is where you should store data.

There is no discussion, csv files are for data transfer, not for active storage. Load the csv to a database & get your data out of there. If you are unsure how to do that, do some basic reading around your language of choice. What you are asking is basic data manipulation, try out some tutorials

Comment: I understand that, but getting it into a javascript graph is the problematic part it seems and csvs are much better for it

Comment: and could you elaborate on the problems it might cause?